# Can not create Postgis extension on mac PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm a Mac user
I have a database .sql copy which I want to use locally, it comes with Postgis extension…
When I run the sql file in Query Tool it shows me error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file 
"/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No 
such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

I tried every single thing including reinstalling postgres, trying to match the versions, reinstalling postgis, restarting postgres service, looking up all possible stackoverflow threads…
Nothing works…
Could anyone help me here please?

Answer (score 1):

i did the folllowing steps in order to fix this issue

```
brew install postgresq@version
brew install postgis
brew services restart postgresql@version
```

i'm using postgresql@14